# Cloudformation to create a private S3 bucket fails with: InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnership

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I've been using the following AWS Cloudformation template to create private S3 buckets (to store ALB logs) for at least two years, but it stopped working now (April 2023). This is the error I now get:

```
Bucket cannot have ACLs set with ObjectOwnership's BucketOwnerEnforced setting (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnership; Request ID:
```

This is the cloudformation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: S3 bucket to store ALB logs

Resources:
  ALBLogsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "pierre-alb-logs-${AWS::AccountId}"
      AccessControl: LogDeliveryWrite
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: ExpireLogs
            ExpirationInDays: 365
            Status: Enabled
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

I know AWS changed something related to public buckets (they're bad). We now must be very explicit when creating public buckets. But this is a private bucket. I searched for the "magic configs" to fix the issue, but no dice... Anyone know what's breaking in my Cloudformation template? What should I remove, what should I add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template seems to work:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: S3 bucket to store ALB logs

Resources:
  ALBLogsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "pierre-alb-logs-${AWS::AccountId}"
      OwnershipControls:
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerEnforced
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: ExpireLogs
            ExpirationInDays: 365
            Status: Enabled
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

Changes:

1. I removed:       `AccessControl: LogDeliveryWrite`
2. I added (this is probably NOT needed, but I added it to be explicit):

```
OwnershipControls:
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerEnforced
```